# The physical meaning of maximal non-integrability of the contact structure

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, complex-systems, integrable-systems

So, basically integrability is equivalent to the existence of an integral manifold of the distribution and I guess, the integral manifold is like a plane of motion where state moves in physical sense.

A contact structure $\xi$ on a smooth manifold $M^{(2n+1)}$ is defined by a contact form $\alpha$ as $\xi = \ker \alpha$ and a contact form is an $1$-form satisfying, $\alpha \wedge (\mathrm{d}\alpha)^n \ne 0$.

Now, the terminology, maximal non-integrability actually comes from the fact that there is no integral manifold of each $(\mathrm{d}\alpha)^k$ and $\alpha \wedge (\mathrm{d}\alpha)^k$. It is just equivalent to the fact that there is no integral manifold of $\xi$.

On the other hand, I heard that the contact structure comes from physical motivation. So, I guess that there may exists a physical fact corresponding to this.

If we restricts the case that the contact manifold (which is a manifold with contact structure) is given as a hypersurface of an ambient symplectic manifold (or the space of free states), then we can tell that "the state under fixed certain value (i.e, it is on the hypersurface) can be access to any state with same certain value" by maximal non-integrability. I think we could interpret this,

> The degree of freedom will not reduced much more than the restriction caused by choosing the hypersurface.

In general, the case of any contact manifold, we may say that

> Any states can be accessible to other states in same space by the choice of proper equation of motion.

So, is it correct interpretation?

Or could you suggest to me the other physical meaning of maximal non-integrability of contact structure? 
Anyway, it seems too mathematical, but I decide to ask here because I focus on the physical meaning of it.

**EDIT:**
My previous interpretation seems wrong. Because there exists a Legendrian submanifold.

However, I found an analogy between the symplectic geometry and the contact geometry.

For example, a Legendrian submanifold of the contact manifold is analogous to a Lagrangian submanifold of the symplectic manifold (and it is roughly, a trace of phase flow in the phase space of given hamiltonian.)

On the other hand, a maximal non-integrability is corresponding to the non-degeneracy of symplectic form. 
[What is a symplectic form intuitively?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19932/what-is-a-symplectic-form-intuitively)

By above, we can think that te non-degeneracy is about the existence and uniqueness of the phase flow by given Hamiltonian.

So, maybe in the case of the contact manifold, it is related to the existence and uniqueness of Reeb flow (or Contact Vector fields) generated by the Hamiltonian (or its analogy), which is related with Dynamics on the contact manifold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, OP is basically correct, at least locally. For a 1st-order dynamical system on a $(2n+1)$-dimensional manifold $(M,\alpha)$ equipped with a globally defined 1-form $\alpha$, a dynamical/evolutionary vector field $X$ satisfies by definition $i_X\mathrm{d}\alpha=0$. An action functional is given by $S[\gamma]=\int\! \gamma^{\ast}\alpha$.  Deviation from [maximally non-integrability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_geometry) is associated with [constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_(classical_mechanics)) and that some equations of motion become algebraic rather than 1st-order ODEs, cf. the [Faddeev-Jackiw method](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9306075) of constrained dynamics. (The precise relation will depend on the chosen notion of time.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you recommend the references how maximally non-integrability can be associated with constaints by dealing with specific examples? I hope to try that with some concrete examples. Thanks again.